# Retrieving MusicBrainz fingerprint with python

Tags: python, audio-fingerprinting, musicbrainz

I struggle to find a way to retrieve the audio fingerprint data from given songs. I tagged those songs with MusicBrainz before and now I want to read it directly from the audiofile. The only way I found with musicbrainzngs was to search (musicbrainzngs.search_artists()) for the song in the MusicBrainz library to find the fingerprint data which is rather inefficient since I have the data in my files already.

Is there a library where I can read it from any given audiofile?

Comment: Which Python module are you using?

Comment: @KristopherIves: `musicbrainzngs` is a Python module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [AcoustID fingerprint](https://musicbrainz.org/doc/AcoustID) is stored in audiofiles, yes, if you tagged your files using [MusicBrainz Picard](https://picard.musicbrainz.org/). What tag exactly depends on the audio file:

- MP3 / ID3V2: `TXXX:Acoustid Fingerprint`
- Vorbis (FLAC, ogg) and APE: `ACOUSTID_FINGERPRINT`
- iTunes MP4:  `----:com.apple.iTunes:Acoustid Fingerprint`

See the [Musicbrainz tag mapping overview](https://picard.musicbrainz.org/docs/mappings/).

You can read audiofile tags with the [`mutagen` project](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/), which is what Picard uses too:

```
import mutagen

tagnames = {
    'audio/mp3': 'TXXX:Acoustid Fingerprint',
    'audio/vorbis': 'ACOUSTID_FINGERPRINT',
    'audio/mp4': '----:com.apple.iTunes:Acoustid Fingerprint'
}

mfile = mutagen.File(musicfile_filename)
if mfile and mfile.mime[0] in tagnames:
    fingerprint = mfile.get(tagnames[mfile.mime[0]])
    if fingerprint is not None:
        try:
            # ID3v2 tag
            fingerprint = fingerprint.text[0]
        except AttributeError:
            # Vorbis
            fingerprint = fingerprint[0]
```